# What is the best practical way to use a complex R package from inside C++ or Java?

Tags: java, c++, rcpp, jri

I am working with this R package that is non-trivial in its dependencies. For instance, it depends on splines::ns() (natural splines) library which has its own dependency on a C module. The input data for the package can be as large as a table of floating point numbers with 100,000 rows and 500 columns.

I would like to use that package from inside C++ or Java code (Java is preferable). I hear there are tools like Rcpp for C++ and JRI for Java, but I have no experience with them. In the end I need to create a very dependable application as opposed to a toy example. If these tools are not very adequate (because of how many dependencies the R package has, or because the amount of input is too large, etc) I will have to rewrite the entire package in C++. What is the best way to go?

Thanks

Comment: For C++, see [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html)

Comment: Can you show us the R code, ill show you how to embed it in java, using JRI :)